# Laravel 8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest with Ajax Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, laravel-8, repository-pattern, http-status-code-403

I am re-doing a part of a website and decided to use Laravel 8 with its built in Repository Pattern. I set up the project and firstly did everything in a WelcomeController that handles all front page methods. Everything worked great. 
I then abstracted the parts of the WelcomeController methods' functionality 
1> Validation of forms => `App\Http\Requests\WelcomeRequest` 
2> Methods used => `App\Interfaces\WelcomeInterface` 
3> Methods used implemented => `App\Repositories\WelcomeRepository` 
4> Injected interface => `App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController` 
5> Binded Interface + Repository => `Providers\RepositoryWebServiceProvider` 
6> Registered service provider `RepositoryWebServiceProvider` => `config/app.php` 
7> Commands => `php artisan config:cache` & `composer dump-autoload`

The front page loaded. Hurrah! 
I then posted contact form values with ajax and received a `403 Forbidden` http response code. 
A] To try and fix this I replaced the `WelcomeRequest` argument from the `WelcomeController store` method with instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` and the request was deposited into the `WelcomeController store` method.
B] But again errorred out on injected interface method `$this->welcomeInterface->contactEmail($request)` with error message `expected WelcomeRequest $request instance Illuminate\Http\Request given`. 
C] The 403 forbidden error only occurs when intstantiating the `App\Http\Requests\WelcomeRequest` class.

**App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController**

```
use App\Http\Requests\WelcomeRequest;
use App\Interfaces\web\WelcomeInterface;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    protected $welcomeInterface;

    public function __construct(WelcomeInterface $welcomeInterface)
    {
        $this->welcomeInterface = $welcomeInterface;
    }

    // ...
    public function store(WelcomeRequest $request) // the request argument causes the error
    {
        return $this->welcomeInterface->requestContact($request);
    }
```

**Routes\web.php**

```
Route::post('/email-contact',  [App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::class, 'store'])->name('email-contact');
```

**App\Http\Requests\WelcomeRequest**

```
class WelcomeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=> 'required|string|max:60',
            'email'=> 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'subject' => 'required|string|max:60',
            'message' => 'nullable|string|max:300',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Your name is required and should not exceed maximum length of 60.',
            'name.max' => 'Your name is required and should not exceed maximum length of 60.',
            'email.required' => 'Email is required.',
            'email.email' => 'Email is incorrect format.',
            'subject.required' => 'The subject is required and should not exceed maximum length of 60.',
            'subject.max' => 'The subject is required and should not exceed maximum length of 60.',
            'message.max' => 'Comment maximum length exceeded.',
            'message.string' => 'Comment is invalid format.',
        ];
    }
}
```

My question is why is the use of the `App\Http\Requests\WelcomeRequest` class that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` giving me a `403 Forbidden` http response? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The `WelcomeRequest` class needed to be authorised before allowing validation. Therefore I changed the following method return --

```
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Was just writing that ;) Glad that you found it!